# Referencing a parameter in enyo.kind()

Tags: javascript, enyo

I have two kinds, one is video kind and the other is a custom kind which contains a video kind. I want to pass a parameter videoStream into the kind VideoPlayerPage and have the subkind Video set this parameter as its src. How  do I do this ?

```
var el  =  new VideoplayerPage({stream: videoStream });
el.renderInto(document.getElementById("formContainer"));
```

---

```
enyo.kind({
        name: "Videoplayer",
        kind : "Video",
        style: "margin-top: 100px;",
        poster : null,
        src : null
    });


enyo.kind({
    name: "VideoplayerPage",
    kind: "FittableRows",
    style: "margin-top: 100px;",
    published: {
        stream : null
    },
    create : function(){
        this.inherited(arguments); 
        this.streamChanged();
        console.log("Creating video page"+ this.stream);
    },
    classes: "data-grid-list-sample data-repeater-sample enyo-fit", 
    components : [
        {kind : "Videoplayer", src: this.stream, showControls : true, fitToWindow : true, autoplay :true},
        {tag: "br"},
        {kind : "moon.Button"},
        {kind : "moon.Button"}
    ],
    streamChanged: function() {
        //this.$.stream.setContent(this.stream);
        this.setStream(this.stream);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind I figured it out . I gave my Video kind a name "player" then in set it in the create  function .

```
create : function(arg){
        this.inherited(arguments); 
        this.$.player.setSrc(this.stream);
}
```

Comment: I would have kept the streamChanged function and done the call to setSrc there, that way it will also update if the stream property is changed.

Comment: @Pre101 that a better way of doing it?

Comment: Yes, I think it's always a good idea to keep the properties you set up connected to their internal representation via the 'changed' function.